# Tab completion doesn't work in curl

Tags: bash

Trying to use tab to autocomplete paths somehow doesn't work in curl

```
curl --output-dir ~/bi
curl --output-dir ~/bi
```

It seems to work in other programs, like vim:

```
vim ~/bi
vim ~/bin/
```

Any way to make it work with curl?

Answer (score 0):

- `curl --out` + TAB works for me and makes it `curl --output`
- `curl --output ~/` and then TAB works for me.
- `--output-dir` seems invalid to me. Can't find it in the man page for curl:

  ```
  $ man curl| grep output-dir
  $ man curl| grep output

       -o, --output <file>
  ```

So it seems a validity check to me: wrong option and after that no auto complete.

Tested with curl 7.68.0.

Looks like a bug to me: someone seems to have forgotten to add `output-dir` to the completion string for curl.

Comment: --output-dir was added in curl 7.73.0: https://curl.se/mail/lib-2020-10/0029.html Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: Though it's true that --output completion works for me, so I guess the completion wasn't configured for that new option yet? Any way to change this?

Comment: Hmm yes I tested with curl 7.68.0.  Does `--output-`  tab complete to `--output-dir`? If not it makes it a bug and should be reported as such: Someone seems to have forgotten to add `output-dir` to the completion string for curl. -- edit ah it does :) file a bug report is probably the quickest method :)